# How to use android phone for SMS Sending app in C#?

Tags: c#, android, asp.net, model-view-controller, sms

I am trying to develop a C# application that will be able to send SMS only through GSM Modem. When we connect a GSM Modem to our laptop/PC then we have to check the Port of that modem from Device manager > Modem > Port. But in this case, I want to connect my android phone as a GSM Modem with my laptop and trying to use the port number of my connected mobile phone but it is not connecting as a modem. Please help me if you have any idea or any possibility to connect the android phone as a GSM Modem to laptop. Here is my mode.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using TextmagicRest;
using TextmagicRest.Model;
using System.Net;
using System.Collections.Specialized;
using System.IO;
using System.IO.Ports;
using System.Threading;


namespace SMS_Sending_App_2
{
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {

            SerialPort sp = new SerialPort();
            sp.PortName = textBox3.Text;
            sp.Open();

            sp.WriteLine("AT" + Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGF=1" + Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CSCS=\"GSM\"" + Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            sp.WriteLine("AT+CMGS=\"" + textBox1.Text + "\"" + Environment.NewLine);
            Thread.Sleep(100);

            sp.Write(new byte[] { 26 }, 0, 1);
            Thread.Sleep(100);
            var response = sp.ReadExisting();

            if (response.Contains("ERROR"))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("SMS failed!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);
            }

            else
                MessageBox.Show("SMS Sent!!!", "Message", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information);

            sp.Close();
        }

        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }



    }

    private void textBox1_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    private void textBox3_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
   }
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is there a reason for not using a modem? I've seen info that ppl are using their phones but I don't know how they do it. It would be a big risk if the phone offered the modem interface just by connecting to the PC.
For better modem communication look at this project : [SMSTerminal](https://github.com/jdahlblom/SMSTerminal)